# How to fix this "Onclick function does not work "

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let username;
document.getElementById("mySubmit").onclick= function(){
  username= document.getElementById("myText").value;
document.getElementById("myH1").textContent= `Hello ${username}`

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="4style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="4userinput.js"></script>

  <h1 id="myH1">Welcome</h1>
<label>user name:</label>
<input id="myText"> 
<br>
<br>
<button id="mySubmit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run code it gave me this error:
4userinput.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')

Can someone help me with this problem. My code works well in the stackoverflow snippet.

Comment: Your code is working correctly in the snippet here.   The most likely reason it's not working in your own instance of the app is that you're trying to run the script before the DOM element exists; make sure you're waiting for document ready

Comment: It runs fine, without errors, in Codepen. Like Daniel suggested, the placement of the script might be an issue. Try moving it under the button and before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thanks for help i put script before the closing body tag as you said. Problem solved thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the JavaScript code executing before the DOM elements are fully loaded, since the script is included before the button even exists. Moving the `<script>` tag to the end of the `<body>` section, should resolve the problem :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="4style.css">
</head>
<body>
  

  <h1 id="myH1">Welcome</h1>
<label>user name:</label>
<input id="myText"> 
<br>
<br>
<button id="mySubmit">Submit</button>


<!-- Move it here -->
<script src="4userinput.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```